# Apex class without field permissions

Tags: apex, permissions

(Interview Question)I have a apex cls or vf page in this apex class or vf page i am updating 10 fields, here i have 2 users A & B for A user i have given only 5 fields permissions to visible, what type of error that user will get and how to do this task

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not appropriate to ask the StackExchange community to answer interview questions for you.

Answer (score 3):

None. If you don't check field level security, you won't get an error. You should always check the field level security of a field before you try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming for user A, out of the 10 fields, 5 fields are visible (Read access) and 5 fields are editable (Read + Edit access).

For the 5 fields with Read access only

1. For VF page these fields will be rendered in Read mode only even if you use `apex:inputField`. So, the user won't be able to edit the fields and there won't be any error.
2. If you try to update the value for these fields from Apex code manually, for e.g. by adding a method and setting the values manually, these values will be saved in database. No error in this case as well.

You will need to check field level permissions in Apex code.

For more details you can read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS) article.